Does a Perceived Lack of Shared Knowledge Force the Speaker to use an Indefinite Article?
I recently found a discussion online about choosing between the articles when specific modifiers are used. The following examples were provided:

[1] Have you ever heard of a fruit called the jacobo berry?


[2] You know the fruit called the jacobo berry? I like to put it on cereal.

In Example 1, the speaker is talking about a specific fruit with a unique identifier (there's only one fruit in the world called the jacobo berry), but they use 'a' to refer to it because they don't believe the listener knows about it.
In Example 2, the speaker uses 'the' because they believe the fruit is well known and thus part of the listener's general knowledge.
My question is this: if we believe the listener doesn't know of something, even if we know it to be a unique entity, is it appropriate (and perhaps advisable) to use an indefinite article?
To emphasise the point that specific entities may require indefinite articles, here's an example sentence in which I use an absurdly specific relative clause in combination with the indefinite article 'a' (we assume that the listener has never heard of this man before):

[3] Yesterday, my mum introduced me to a man who travelled to Mars with his brother Jake Goodwin and his stepdad, Terry Thatcher, after winning the 'Travel to Mars' competition of 1967 when he was sixteen.

Edit:
Here are two real-life examples of the usage of the indefinite article 'a' and the definite article, from The Hunger Games series:

[4] Along with Finnick and Gale, the squad includes five soldiers from 13. Jackson, a middle-aged woman who's Boggs's second in command, looks kind of sluggish but can hit things the rest of us can't.


[5] Suddenly he falls into a Capitol accent as he mimics Effie Trinket, the maniacally upbeat woman who arrives once a year to read out the names at the leaping.

In Example 4, there's no doubt the writer knows there's only one 'middle-aged woman who's Bogg's second in command,' but she chooses to use 'a' because the reader is presumed to lack this knowledge.
In Example 5, the writer chooses to use 'the,' presumably because she assumes the reader will understand who the woman is based on the modification 'who arrives once a year to read out the names at the leaping.'

I don't think the final example has much to do with whether anybody knows the person being referred to - it's that "a man who travelled to Mars" is a non-specific class of person which isn't specified down to a unique instance until later in the sentence. If the sentence were "my mum introduced me to the winner of the 1967 'Travel to Mars' competition", you'd use the definite article whether you or anyone else had heard about them or not.

The reason is not about presumed knowledge. It's about generality and specificity like any other question re a/an versus the. Those things never change.

This is a good question! In practice I think I'd potentially use this where the examples use a and that where the examples use the. "she introduced me to this guy who travelled to mars...", "have you ever heard of this fruit called...", "you know that fruit called...". I'm not sure if drawing the analogy gives any clarity, but if you don't like using a for a unique entity, this is a good alternative.

@Lambie can you explain some more? You might be right, I'm just not understanding entirely. Why does the specificity change between [1] and [2]?

@Kaia I met the man who liked football. [previous conversation assumed: specific] I met a man who like football. [a generality, can be said at any point]. In 1 and 2, it is the desire of the speaker that comes into play. NOT grammar. In either case, the listener may or may not have heard about that fruit. Whether or not he/she has is irrelevant and in any case, when we ask questions like this, it reflects on us, not on the interlocutor.

@Lambie "the desire of the speaker" == "presumed knowledge", right? In any case, "a man who likes football" is different from the case at hand, because there are many such men.

@Kaia No, not at all. And my sentence was: 1) the x who liked y. versus 2) An x who liked y. The difference is expressing specificity versus generality.  I saw an apple on the table. [not specific] Where did it go? Versus: I saw the apple on the table. The one you put there last night (specific). In fact, next time you plan to leave me an apple*, leave the apple on the kitchen table, not the living room table.//a/an versus the is not a marker of presumption of knowledge.

Note that "You know the fruit called the jacobo berry?" and "Do you know the fruit called the jacobo berry?" have different meanings. The second simply asks whether the hearer knows the fruit. The first states that the speaker is assuming the hearer knows the fruit, and is possibly asking for confirmation.

It doesn't force you to use the indefinite article, because you could instead say:

Have you heard of the jacobo berry?

The reason for the indefinite article with "a fruit" is because "fruit" is a common noun. Saying "a fruit called the jacobo berry" is like saying "a dog named Rover" or "a man called Dave".
Saying "a fruit called the Jacobo berry" gives more information - that it is a fruit! When you're asking someone if they've ever heard of something there must be at least some doubt that they have, so you're helping them out by telling them that the Jacobo berry is a fruit.

I don't think this explanation really explains why "you know the fruit called the jacobo berry?" is acceptable. If fruit is a common noun, shouldn't you always say "a fruit called..." not "the fruit called"?

@kaia you're right, but I don't think these endless "why do we say this not that" questions need to be addressed point by point. There are countless answered questions on this site about the differences between the definite and indefinite article. I prefer to address the original quote that the OP has found, not the endless variations that they come up with. That would make it a proof-reading question.

@Astralbee I'd argue that 'a fruit called the jacobo berry' isn't like 'a dog named Rover' and 'a man called Dave,' as it's fair to assume there are multiple dogs called Rover and men called Dave. What I'm getting at here is that there's only one fruit called the jacobo berry, and the speaker knows this all too well. Given the speaker's knowledge, it's clear, to me at least, that they chose 'a' solely for the listener's benefit. This is even clearer when we focus on 1 being a question that implies uncertainty and 2 being a question that implies possible familiarity.

@MJAda  It's all on the speaker, not his/her interlocutor. The speaker MIGHT or MIGHT NOT know. You assume too much. :)

There are times when the speaker doesn't know whether what they have just learned about is factual or possibly an error in a blog post or an error in what someone has told them or possibly that they have misheard something. For example:

Have you ever heard of a tree called a bumsquat?  There was a woman with an Australian accent on the train across the aisle from me telling the person next to her how delicious the fruit was.
Have you heard anything about a first-time voter discount at the supermarket? I saw it on social media. Supposedly they're offering people who have never voted before (18 year-olds, I imagine, or maybe newly naturalized citizens) a 50% discount on a frozen turkey.

The definite article would confer existence upon the thing, which the speaker is not quite ready and willing to do.

This explanation does apply in many contexts, but not in all. If a secretary says to his boss, “Did you want to meet with a Jeff Goodman? He called and said you had suggested he make an appointment,” the secretary’s question is not so much about the caller’s existence or identity as about the boss’s possible acquaintance with him and desire or willingness to meet with him. And it strongly suggests that the secretary himself does not know the caller.

@PaulTanenbaum  It's not an "explanation" that is meant to fit all possible circumstances but a particular kind of circumstance that licenses the indefiniite article at the expense of the definite.  That said, I think your context fits. There is a reticence expressed by the indefinite article that applies there.

Or maybe this guy who the secretary doesn't recogize is an interloper that should be dismissed?

Thanks for your answer, @TimR. However, I think it perhaps assumes that the speaker is unsure of something, which I never implied. In fact, I'm trying to emphasis the opposite: the speaker knows for certain of the existence of the jacobo berry. They just don't know if the person they're talking to does.

@MJAda If the speaker is certain that the jacobo berry exists, the speaker will say "the jacobo berry" to indicate that the speaker considers it to exist, and "a jacobo berry" perhaps out of a sense of politeness if the speaker believes the listener may not know of it.  The indefinite article could indicate (perhaps falsely, a "white lie" for politeness sake) that the speaker is only recently aware of the jacobo berry. But there is certainly no requirement to use the indefinite article with something the speaker knows to exist, no matter what the state of the listener's knowledge.

@TimR I agree the speaker won't use 'a jacobo berry,' but my example was 'a fruit called the jacobo berry.' The modification of the relative clause seems to change things.

I. OP's Query and clarification:

My question is this: if we believe the listener doesn't know of something, even if we know it to be a unique entity, is it appropriate (and perhaps advisable) to use an indefinite article?

Yes, it's both appropriate and advisable to use an indefinite article (a/an) when introducing a unique entity to someone presumed unfamiliar with it, even if you are aware that it is specific and unique.
Key Points to Note:.

Article choice depends on the listener's assumed knowledge rather than the speaker's.
Use "the" when you believe the listener is familiar with or can identify the entity; use a/an when you’re introducing something new to them.

It is not necessary to always use "the" for unique entities.
Even unique entities can take either "a or the", depending on the context and familiarity with the listener, as explained in the Cambridge Dictionary reference below. (Converse is also true)

Reference Cambridge dictionary:.
We don’t use the when the noun is not known to the listener or reader:
Last Sunday, we saw a film called ‘Nightmare’. (The speaker doesn’t think that the listener knows of this film.).
A/an and the: typical errors

II. OP’s Example Sentences:.

"Have you ever heard of a fruit called the jacobo berry?".
Correct use of "a" since the speaker assumes the listener is unfamiliar.
"You know the fruit called the jacobo berry?".
Correct use of "the" since the speaker assumes shared knowledge.
"Yesterday, my mum introduced me to a man who travelled to Mars...".
"Correct use of "a" since it is presumed the listener is unlikely to know this person.*

III. Additional Examples Showing Use of Either "a/an" or "the":.
In these examples, using an indefinite article (a/an) suggests the speaker presumes the information is new to the listener, while the implies the listener is familiar with or can identify it.

"Have you seen an English movie named Titanic?".
"Have you seen the English movie Titanic?"
"Do you know an Austrian composer named Mozart?".
"Do you know the Austrian composer Mozart?"
"Did you ever taste a French dish named Caviar?".
"Did you ever taste the French dish Caviar?"

Note: In each of the above sentence "a" is used when the speaker thinks that the fact is unknown to the listener.(Refer Cambridge dictionary link above)

In your three final examples I would expect there might be more than one possible movie/teacher/dish. If I wanted to specify there was only one I would use the.

I like most of this answer, but I'd agree with Peter that some of the examples don't sound right. I don't have an issue with Example 1, which lines up with another example I've found ('It's a saying from thousands of years ago, written in a language called Latin about a place called Rome'). However, 2 and 3 don't sound natural to my ears, presumably because you've used the appositive. You could say, 'I ate a French dish, Caviar' or 'I ate the French dish Caviar.'

@MJAda  Is this your own sentence? Or did you find it some where - Have you ever heard of a fruit called the jacobo berry? This example is similar to my caviar example. This is the nth time my reference from Cambridge or British Council is thrown into the dustbin. Sometimes the reason given is  "typing error".  don't rely on dictionaries.  the teacher is wrong or the book is wrong. If you visit the Cambridge  Corpus site you will find the required information which is making you confused. That is if you trust  it is authentic o'wise you can be content with the info. you got here.

Anyway here is how the rule stated in your post works:
"Have you ever tasted a French dish named caviar?"
In this sentence, a is appropriate because it presents caviar as something the listener may not be familiar with, even though caviar is a specific dish. This use aligns with the rule that an indefinite article can introduce a unique or specific entity when it’s assumed to be new to the listener.

@JamesMathai, the fruit example in my post isn't mine. I found it on a forum discussing a similar issue. I can see you've edited your Example 3, so yes, it's perfectly fine now. It's only Example 2 that gives me pause. Do you have a link to where I can find that information on the Cambridge Corpus site? Thanks :)

@MJAda The Cambridge Corpus is a paid site. I only saw the sentence I quoted but the link is not available for non members. Actually your post interested me and I spent some time researching it and found that the rule is valid. And it is applied so all your sentences with a/the are correct.

@Peter How are my examples different than the Cambridge dictionary example in the link. We don’t use the when the noun is not known to the listener or reader:
Last Sunday, we saw a film called ‘Nightmare’. (The speaker doesn’t think that the listener knows of this film.)
A/an and the: typical errors

@JamesMathai, I don't believe the simple Cambridge rule deals with the subtleties. If you say to me either I saw the film called 'Nightmare' or I saw a film called 'Nightmare' I will learn the same information, but for the first I would expect you to have been emphasising the title and adding that it is a film, and in the second I would expect you to have been emphasising that you saw a film and adding its title. However I met a girl called Carrie is much better than I met the girl called Carrie unless I know that you know who Carrie is. But "girl called Carrie" is not unique.

@Peter Do you think Cambridge dictionary explanation and the example sentence with indefinite article is incorrect.  Last Sunday, we saw a film called ‘Nightmare’. (The speaker doesn’t think that the listener knows of this film.)

@JamesMathai I think the example is poor. Speaking of "the film called Nightmare" is enough to identify the film to most people, even those who do not know of it before hearing the sentence. Using "the" asserts there is only one such film, and that the hearer can (by the end of the sentence) identify it. I think my example of I met a girl called Carrie is better, and the explanation would be that the speaker does not think the hearer knows who Carrie is, even after hearing the sentence. This is because there could be many girls called Carrie.

There can be no difference in meaning between:
Do you know a berry called the Jacobo berry?
and
Do you know the berry called the Jacobo berry?
That said, using one or the other is a speaker-side thing.
The first with a suggests the speaker might not know it and wants confirmation from the interlocutor. But in neither case, is there any assumption of shared knowledge. As a native speaker, I would use the one with a, if I didn't know it. I'm hoping my interlocutor does.
It will mostly depend on intonation used in the question.

Please disregard the dv/s
